# View resized even after setting contentHuggingPriority to defaultHigh

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uistackview

I have a vertical stackView.

```
bodyStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
bodyStackView.axis = .vertical
bodyStackView.alignment = .fill
bodyStackView.distribution = .fill
bodyStackView.spacing = 8.0
bodyStackView.backgroundColor = .yellow
```

and two/three views get added to it.

```
bodyStackView.addArrangedSubview(titleStackView)
bodyStackView.addArrangedSubview(priceStackView)
bodyStackView.addArrangedSubview(subscriptionInEligibleLabel)

titleStackView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
priceStackView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
```

I want the last or the bottom-most view to stretch.
I have set the "ContentHuggingPriority", and yet the first or the top-most view is getting stretched.
How do we control this?
[image]

Comment: Instead of settings priority you need to set height constraints to first 2 views.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you have 3 stack views in your `bodyStackView`, but assuming you have a valid reason...

You need to set the `Content Hugging Priority` on the ***labels***, not on the stack views.